# LiveData observe() not called

Tags: android, dao, android-room, android-livedata

My observer callback is not being called, can you point out what am I doing wrong ? My application is really simple since I'm just testing this architecture

MainActivity code

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UpcomingMoviesViewModel.class);
viewModel.getUpcomingMovies().observe(this, upcomingMovies -> {
        // NOT CALLED !!!
        for(UpcomingMovies movie : upcomingMovies) {
            Log.d("Upcoming", "Movie - " + movie.movie.title);
        }
    });
```

ViewModel code

```
private LiveData<List<UpcomingMovies>> mUpcomingMovies;
private MovieRepository movieRepository;

public UpcomingMoviesViewModel(@NonNull Application application ) {
    super(application);
    movieRepository = MovieRepository.getsInstance(application); 
}

public LiveData<List<UpcomingMovies>> getUpcomingMovies() {
    mUpcomingMovies = movieRepository.getUpcomingMovies();
    return mUpcomingMovies;
}
```

And my repository method

```
public LiveData<List<UpcomingMovies>> getUpcomingMovies(){
    if(movieDao.loadUpcomingMovies().getValue() == null) {
        webService.getUpcomingMovies(api_key).
                enqueue(new Callback<MovieResults>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MovieResults> call, Response<MovieResults> response) {
                        MovieResults results = response.body();
                        if(results == null) return;
                        new insertAsyncTask(movieDao).execute(results.movies.toArray(new Movie[results.movies.size()]));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MovieResults> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("Retrofit error", t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
    return movieDao.loadUpcomingMovies();
}

private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Movie, Void, Void> {

    private final MovieDao mAsyncTask;

    insertAsyncTask(MovieDao dao){
        mAsyncTask = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Movie... movies) {
        long [] results = mAsyncTask.insertMovies(Arrays.asList(movies));
        long [] results2 = mAsyncTask.insertUpcomingMovies(Arrays.asList(movies));
        return null;
    }
}
```

Both `results` and `results2` return 20 numbers, which I attribute it to the fact I receive 20 movies. 
What have I done wrong here ? Thanks for ur time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement LifeCyclebserver to viewModel and add this in your activity:

```
getLifecycle().addObserver(viewModel);
```

Comment: `postValue` is a method from `MutableLiveData` not `LiveData`

Comment: Yea, initialize your mUpcomingMovies to MutableLiveData. I forgot to add that code. You are also sure that data is coming till viewModel?

Comment: Throws exception saying `mUpcomingMovies` is null

Comment: Initialize like this: private MutableLiveData<List<UpcomingMovies>> mUpcomingMovies = new MutableLiveData<List<UpcomingMovies>>()

Comment: I'm using this line `mUpcomingMovies.postValue(movieRepository.getUpcomingMovies().getValue());` . It's still not getting called

Comment: Did you add this:  getLifecycle().addObserver(viewModel) in the activity?

Comment: No never saw that in the tutorials. Also that doesn't compile

Comment: You have added this in the dependencies right?
'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

Comment: Yes I had the 1.1.0, but I updated it. Still the same error. It expects a `LifecycleObserver` not a `AndroidViewModel`

Comment: Actually my viewModel implements LifecyleObserver, that why i said that. You are also sure that data is coming till viewModel?

Comment: It worked.. What made it work was implementing LifecycleObserver. It wasnt working with mutableLiveData. Why is the implementation necessary do u know ? Thanks :)

Comment: Because we need to observe the life cycle state changes right (which is one of the best things about these components)

Comment: Seems to me it should be automatic, I've never seen in any example this obligatory implementation. Anyways, thanks! No need to refer MutableLiveData in your answer. Just update it with the Lifecycle stuff

Comment: I mentioned MutableLiveData because using postValue we can directly put into MainThread instead of us switching threads if at all you are switching threads

Comment: I'm not, only when doing `Inserts` in my repo. Thanks good to know :)

Comment: Can we use `viewLifecycleOwner` api?

Answer (score 0):

Remember your viewModel needs to have a constructor that takes in no parameters

Comment: Not sure if that answers the question. The OP did not get a NullReferenceException, so it seems their ViewModel instantiated properly. (I'm guessing OP derived their ViewModel from `AndroidViewModel`).

Answer (score 0):

For Java in the source and destination fragments, call;

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

Not

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

`getActivity` instead of `this` allows you to reference the same activity